# Sentiment Analysis_Apache HBase_Apache Storm

Tags: hbase, apache-storm, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to do sentiment analysis on Apache Storm and retrieve results using Hbase. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at my [prototype project](https://github.com/dgreenshtein/storm-twitter-sentiments).
Doing very simple sentiments analysis, then words trending and writing results to HDFS. Maybe you can reuse some parts for your needs.